# Facebook authentication: server-side versus client-side. Python/Django

Tags: python, django, facebook-login, django-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have a website that essentially requires that the user be logged in to see anything. If they are not logged in then they are redirected to the front page and a login form.

I currently use Django's standard authentication and test for authentication server-side before returning the page.

I now want to add Facebook login and authentication. Does this mean that I need to make a server-side call to Facebook and verify authentication every single time that a user navigates to any page? It seems that this will add quite a number of calls and potential page delays.

Or, is this not really a concern (Facebook call is fast) or is there some other clever way that I am missing? Somehow move the call client-side where I believe that Facebook uses caching?

I've looked at some of the Django/Facebook packages, but none seem to explain the overall strategy, which is what I'm looking to understand. The tutorials that I have looked at describe how to login, but don't worry about what happens once a user logs out of Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the user logs in once using facebook (this will make a request to facebook).

once is logged in, it will behave just as a normal django user (most apps create a Django User for each facebook user)

Only when the access token is expired (the "password" for using the facebook data) than you will need to make a connection to facebook again.

Ill recommend you to use [Python Social Auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/) which basically does everything for you.

Comment: Then what happens if a user logs out of Facebook - would they still expect to be logged into my web app? Or would they expect that logging out of Facebook logs them out of every app that uses their Facebook login, in which case, I need to keep checking whether they are still logged in to Facebook?

Comment: well this is a good question. it is totally up to you: do you give the option to register to your site using facebook? or the user in your site is *the* facebook user? more common is the first option, so even if the user is *not* logged in to facebook, it doesn't mean he cannot be logged in to your site. but whenever he will need to login to your site again, he will need to use his facebook account, because facebook-users don't have passwords in your site. this is the main issue about it: the authentication part.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's certainly easier if Facebook and my app don't have to be so connected. Do you happen to know if they need to be logged in to facebook for me to access their facebook info - like their email or whatever else they may have given me permission for?

Comment: No they don't need to be. When the authentication process is complete, you get some basic details like email, list of interests, likes..in the response from Facebook. And most important the they give you the  "access token": which gives you access to the user info whenever you want (but only for what the user agreed to give of course). this access token will be expired in 60 days I think, and than you need to get a permission for another one again.

Comment: Thanks, that's a big help.